# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Where is the error in writing this post?

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#teacher").clik(function({
        $("#login_teachers").slideToggle();
        $("#login_teachers").css('display', 'block');
        $("#login_parents, #login_students").css('display', 'none'),
    });

    $("#parents").clik(function({
        $("#login_parents").slideToggle();
        $("#login_parents").css('display', 'block');
        $("#login_teachers, #login_students").css('display', 'none'),
    });        

    $("#students").clik(function(){ 
        $("#login_students").slideToggle();
        $("#login_students").css('display', 'block');
        $("#login_parents, #login_teachers").css('display', 'none');
    });   
});
</script>
```

I'm getting the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different errors (each repeated three times):

1. There's a typo in the `click` event handlers definition: your code wrongly contains **`clik`**, instead.
2. Every last line of the event handlers, for example `$("#login_teachers, #login_students").css('display', 'none'),` is terminated by a **comma** instead of a semicolon.

The *"Unexpected token '}'"* error is due to the second mistake.

Comment: 3. `function({` occurs on the first two functions, when it should be `function() {`